# Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt while try to connect Oracle db

Tags: c#, oracle, windows-services

We have a Windows service which tries to connect to an Oracle DB. If the data is not present it tries multiple times to fetch the data. We used a thread to sleep the process for 1 minute and retry, but after multiple attempts it throws the above error at the `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

Has anyone had the same issue?

I've tried to search for the solution but nothing worked in my case.

Comment: "Attempted to read or write protected memory" means that something is *very wrong*; either a bug in some `unsafe` code, or some managed code that .NET is wrapping. If this happens when using a library (such as the Oracle ADO.NET provider), it sounds like a bug in that library, that should be logged (with a repro example if possible) with the library vendor. If *you* have some `unsafe` (or similar) code in this area, then: can we see it?

Comment: Could you post the code that you've written to read the database in your post, please?